# Rename name of this Forum, or gain more web activity

Tags: discussion, tags, scope

Why is this StackExchange called Martial Arts? Western Boxing, Dutch Kickboxing, and others are not traditional martial arts from the east. See dictionary terms below specifying Far East and East Asian. In effort to gain more attention and marketing from the internet, should we rename this to "Self Defense and Fighting" stack exchange. Open to any other names

Let me know if this question is off topic. I enjoy this site, and trying to garner more attention as only handful of people and answerers seem to use it. It should be getting more web usage/activity as its very helpful.

https://www.britannica.com/sports/martial-art

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/martial-art

> martial art, any of various fighting sports or skills, mainly of East Asian origin, such as kung fu (Pinyin gongfu), judo, karate, and
> kendō.
>
> A martial art is one of the methods of fighting, often without
> weapons, that come from the Far East, for example kung fu, karate, or
> judo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would generally say that martial arts is a better umbrella term than "fighting".

It may be discussed whether it should not be "martial art and self-defense stackexchange".

My personal stance on that would be that this probably will end up in many "what if" questions on self-defense which, by design, are a bad format for StackExchange since answers are either overly specific if the question allows for that or, more likely, generic and not very useful as such.

Answer (score 5):

If 'martial' means 'relating to fighting or war' (Oxford Languages), 'Martial art' refers to all fighting arts and is not a term restricted by origin.

Comment: well I guess it depends on which dictionary then, most of them are saying related to East origin, etc

Comment: @mattsmith5. The first two paragraphs of [Wikipedia's entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martial_arts) are useful.